# Can't compress a recycled bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to save a Layout into an Image in the SDCard but I get this error. I tried several codes I found in this forum but all of them have the same compress call that is giving the error.

This is the code I use for saving the image:

```
private Bitmap TakeImage(View v) {
        Bitmap screen = null;
        try {
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());

            v.buildDrawingCache(true);
            screen = v.getDrawingCache();
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return screen;
    }
```

And this is the code for saving it in the SDCard:

```
private void saveGraph(Bitmap graph, Context context) throws IOException {
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "test.jpg");
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        graph.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();

        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> Can't compress a recycled  bitmap in the compress call!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is probably causing the bitmap to be recycled:

```
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
```

If you want the bitmap to hang around longer, then you should copy it.

Comment: You shouldn't take out the line; the bitmap provided from the cache may be recycled at any time by the view which owns it. You really need to take your own copy of the Bitmap using `Bitmap.copy()` instead.

Comment: Can you explain how to copy it?

Comment: Like I said, call `Bitmap.copy()`. Here is the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copy(android.graphics.Bitmap.Config, boolean)

Comment: Worked for me as well as I just had to move the code a little bit later down my method. I checked my code in Xamarin.Android and was setting it back to false too early.

Answer (score 19):

This resolved my issues.

```
View drawingView = get_your_view_for_render;
drawingView.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bitmap = drawingView.getDrawingCache(true).copy(Config.RGB_565, false);
drawingView.destroyDrawingCache();
// bitmap is now OK for you to use without recycling errors.
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:
you only need to copy the bitmap.

```
imageneViewer.setImageBitmap(lienzo.getDrawingCache().copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, false));
```